# SQL Error number 10620 duplicate entry 97079 on primary key

Tags: mysql

I am trying to replicate Server A to server B but getting this error

> error no 1062 duplicate entry 97079 on primary key

Please help me to find the problem.

Comment: Should we guess how the code looks?

Comment: when you insert then table B have same key

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you are mentioning is: The replication is trying to insert a record into a table of the slave database with primary key 97079, but there already exists a record with primary key 97079.

Most likely, your two databases are not in the same state. Before doing a replication, first dump the data from your master database and read it into the slave database.